# Making vector push-front improved to O(1) / 8192

Tags: c++, c++11

After working on it, my regenerating reserve vector may not be so bad after all. (In [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326712/speeding-vector-push-back), I presented a vector with a regenerating reserve, faster at `push_back` when reserve can't be predicted).

Deque may be cool, but the vector is faster. So, I ameliorated my Vector, with two reserves: one before the begin and another after the end, thus, enabling `push_front` in a vector very quickly (`push_back` is still better than a normal vector).

With a RESA of 8192, and 1000 `push_front`, I had this results (computer is a Lenovo Think Center):

Duration of old `push_front` == 199 ticks (`insert(v.begin () , s)`)

Duration of new `push_front` == 5 ticks

What do you think about it?

```
#ifndef __VECTOR2_HPP
#define __VECTOR2_HPP

class Concept {
public :
  Concept () {}
  ~Concept () {}
  enum const_e { //ok uw : PS = 512, FS 1024
    RESA = 8192
  };
};
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Concept.hpp"
#include <exception>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
class Vector : public std::vector<T> {
public :
  class Error : public std::exception {
  public :
    Error (std::string val = "") throw () : val_ (val) {}
    ~Error () throw () {}
    const char* what () throw () {
      std::string s ("Vector Error :");
      s += val_;
      return s.c_str();
    } 
  private :
    std::string val_;
  };
  typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin () {
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator i (std::vector<T>::begin ());
    i += lresa_;
    return i;
  }
  typename std::vector<T>::iterator end () {
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator i (std::vector<T>::end ());
    i -= rresa_;
    return i;
  }
  typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator begin () const {
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator i (std::vector<T>::begin ());
    i += lresa_;
    return i;
  }
  typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator end () const {
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator i (std::vector<T>::end ());
    i -= rresa_;
    return i;
  }
  typename std::vector<T>::reverse_iterator rbegin () {
    typename std::vector<T>::reverse_iterator i (std::vector<T>::rbegin ());
    i += rresa_;
    return i;
  }
  typename std::vector<T>::reverse_iterator rend () {
    typename std::vector<T>::reverse_iterator i (std::vector<T>::rend ());
    i -= lresa_;
    return i;
  }
  typename std::vector<T>::const_reverse_iterator rbegin () const {
    typename std::vector<T>::const_reverse_iterator i (std::vector<T>::rbegin ());
    i += rresa_;
    return i;
  }
  typename std::vector<T>::const_reverse_iterator rend () const {
    typename std::vector<T>::const_reverse_iterator i (std::vector<T>::rend ());
    i -= lresa_;
    return i;
  }
  Vector () : std::vector<T> (2*(size_t) Concept::RESA, T()), lresa_ ((size_t) Concept::RESA), rresa_ ((size_t) Concept::RESA) {
  }
  size_t size () const {
    size_t s (std::vector<T>::size ());
    s -= lresa_;
    s -= rresa_;
    return s;
  }
  Vector (int n, T t0) : std::vector<T> (n + 2*(size_t) Concept::RESA, t0), lresa_ ((size_t) Concept::RESA), rresa_ ((size_t) Concept::RESA) {
  }
  Vector (const Vector& v) : std::vector<T> (v), lresa_ (v.lresa_), rresa_ (v.rresa_) {
  }
  bool operator == (const Vector& v) const {
    return std::equal (begin (), end (), v.begin ());
  }
  bool operator != (const Vector& v) const {
    return !operator == (v);
  }
  T& operator [] (const size_t &s) {
    return std::vector<T>::operator [] (s+lresa_);
  }
  void push_front (const T& t) {
    if (!lresa_) {
      std::vector<T>::insert (std::vector<T>::begin (), (size_t) Concept::RESA, t);
      lresa_ = (size_t) Concept::RESA;
    }
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator i (std::vector<T>::begin ());
    i += lresa_ -1;
    *i = t;
    --lresa_;
  }
  void push_back (const T& t) {
    if (!rresa_) {
      std::vector<T>::insert (std::vector<T>::end (), (size_t) Concept::RESA, t);
      rresa_ = (size_t) Concept::RESA;
    }
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator i (std::vector<T>::end ());
    i -= rresa_;
    *i = t;
    --rresa_;
  }
  //can be optimized,but that s not the topic
  Vector& operator = (const Vector& v) {
    std::vector<T>::operator = (v);
    lresa_ = v.lresa_;
    rresa_ = v.rresa_;
    return *this;
  }
  //intelligent resize to do  
  //at the moment just stupid
  void resize (size_t n) {
    std::vector<T>::resize (n + lresa_ + rresa_);
  }
private :
  size_t lresa_;
  size_t rresa_;
};
#endif
```

Comment: It cannot be O(1) as you sometime need to grow the vector and move items.. Maybe **amortized O(1)**?

Comment: It would help to add links to your previous question(s). Also, it's unclear what `Concept.hpp` is; without it, we can't tell what `Concept::RESA` is. ("RESA" is not an obvious acronym; and then you use it again in `lresa_` and `rresa_`. I don't know what those identifiers are meant to signify.)

Comment: Concept::RESA is a constant that should be smaller than stack size. It's the only thing declared in Concept.hpp.  you may set it to 4 and test and then set it to 8K

Comment: lresa_ stands for left reserve and rresa_ stands for right reserve

Comment: You've been told repeatedly that invalidating answers by editing your question is not allowed, Since this question had been locked before and you invalidated the answers again, I have locked this post permanently. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 5):

Your class requires T to be DefaultConstructible for an empty container. `std::vector` doesn't.

`__VECTOR2_HPP` - change to `VECTOR2_HPP__`

Don't publicly inherit from such complex classes as `std::vector`. For example, think of the results of calling `front()` on an object of your class.

There is no reason for a hardcoded constant like `Concept::RESA`. Make it a parameter. Better yet, make the actual extent exponentially growing.

There is no need for `rresa_`. The `std::vector` itself handles it better.

Where do you use `Vector::Error`?

No modifications of your container other than by just looping through `push_back()` and/or `push_front()` are thought out at all. The ones inherited from `std::vector` are broken, and even the ones written by yourself are going to lead to unexpected results with `T` being something like `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 3):

Start by adding a type for you base class:

```
typedef std::vector<T> base;
```

This can be used to simplify many of your declarations within your code.

Your various `begin`/`end` functions can be simplified

```
auto begin() {
    return base::begin() + lresa_;
}
```

Unlike `vector`, your reserved areas contain default constructed objects.  While this is not an issue for basic types like `int`, for more complicated types this can result in a performance hit and additional memory consumption.

Your `operator==` compares the contents of the reserve areas, which can cause incorrect comparison results.  An easy way this can happen is if an element is added then removed (although you do not have any form of remove).  Your `reserve` can be used as a remove proxy, and will leave valid constructed objects in your reserve area if the vector is shrunk.

You lack a `operator[] const` function.

How will you handle a move constructor?

You can improve your spacing/formatting.  Having a space between a function name and the parenthesis is pretty uncommon and (IMHO) makes it harder to read.  The overall indentation level is a bit shallow (3 or 4 spaces is more typical).

Comment: For your comment about indentation, I like to guess what 's the line is doing without scrolling, and prefer a small indentation. Is this really important ?

Comment: I could do a operator [], but anyone here is able to do this. I prefered concentrate on method push_front

Answer (score 3):

- This is not what anyone would expect when using a `Vector`. It's closer to a `Deque`.
- Use `std::size_t`, not `size_t`.
- It looks like we're casting `Concept::RESA` to `size_t` every time it's used. Perhaps it should be declared as `std::size_t` to start with.

---

[Inheritance is not a good fit here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7110262/673679)

- `std::vector` does not have a virtual destructor.
- `std::vector` does not use virtual functions, so the added functions do **not** override the normal functionality. For example, any function that accepts a `std::vector<T> const&` will accept a `Vector<T>` argument. It will then call the `std::vector` interface, and silently do the wrong thing.
- `std::vector` has many other functions, e.g. `front()`, `back()`, `data()`, `cbegin()` etc. that are accessible to class users due to public inheritance, but will not do the expected thing when called, because they aren't overridden.
- Even if all these other functions are re-implemented, the interface of `std::vector` may change in future, for example adding a new function. New functions will be accessible, but do something unexpected / wrong.

In short, we have to use composition here, not inheritance.